# Setting Enumerate Value to a Variable changes the output of a function

Tags: python, enumerate

I'm new to the enumeration function, I've only just started to use it. In this code block, I'm enumerating "height" multiple times:

```
class Solution(object):
    def maxArea(self, height):
        """
        :type height: List[int]
        :rtype: int
        """
        if len(height) == 2:
            return (min(height))
        
        maxArea = -1
        for i, a in enumerate(height):
            maxIndex, maxDistance = i, 0
            
            for j, s in enumerate(height):
                distance = abs(j-i)
                
                if distance>maxDistance and s>=a:
                    maxIndex, maxDistance = j, distance
            
            area = abs(maxIndex - i) * a
            maxArea = max(area,maxArea)
        
        return maxArea
```

I thought a way to optimize this was to set enumerate(height) to a variable to decrease the amount of times the height was put into the enumerate function:

```
class Solution(object):
    def maxArea(self, height):
        """
        :type height: List[int]
        :rtype: int
        """
        if len(height) == 2:
            return (min(height))
        
        maxArea = -1
        enumeratedHeight = enumerate(height)
        for i, a in enumeratedHeight:
            maxIndex, maxDistance = i, 0
            
            for j, s in enumeratedHeight:
                distance = abs(j-i)
                
                if distance>maxDistance and s>=a:
                    maxIndex, maxDistance = j, distance
            
            area = abs(maxIndex - i) * a
            maxArea = max(area,maxArea)
        
        return maxArea
```

I tested this new function on this case [1,8,6,2,5,4,8,3,7]. The before function correctly answered 49, but this one returns 8?

(**this code is to solve Container With Most Water on Leetcode**, I know it's inefficient, but I've been told to write inefficient code if I can't find an efficient solution)

Comment: `enumerate` objects can only be iterated over once.

Comment: @rdas is there a way for me to not enumerate height more than once then?

Comment: Your first solution does just that.

Comment: You need to loop over the contents of `height` multiple times unless your algorithm itself can be changed. There's no way to do that without looping over the contents of `height` multiple times. Is there a specific reason for trying to change how you're doing it? It feels like something that, even if it did work, would give no benefit.

Comment: @rdas I'm confused, in the first solution, I called enumerate(height) multiple times. Does that not add up to the computation needed?

Comment: @Kemp I'm trying to change how I'm doing it because I thought calling enumerate(height) multiple times would increase the time needed. I'm not trying to change the algorithm itself, I'm trying to optimize it.

Comment: This isn't an optimisation. `enumerate` doesn't add any meaningful overhead compared to simple iteration over the list, which you need to do anyway. The way to optimise is to find parts of the code that are actually taking too long and targeting them. Have you done any benchmarking? Does the script actually take too long to run? If you have 9 items in your list as per your example then it'll take no time at all. If you have a thousand it'll take no time.

Comment: @Kemp What do you mean? Enumerate iterates through the list every single time it's called. If I run a loop with enumerate(height) within a for loop that iterates over a list, isn't that almost double the iterations over the list?

Comment: You have two loops. No matter what you do, they're going to iterate over the list. That's what the loops do. Regardless of whether you use `enumerate` or not, you still have a loop that still needs to iterate over the list. If it doesn't iterate then there's no loop. Loops iterate over things.